# A navbar cant't recognize a static file in my Django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to use a CSS style in a static file for a navbar but it is not recognized and i get an error:

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[04/Mar/2024 17:57:46] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3581
[04/Mar/2024 18:17:46] "GET /list?page=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1374
```

views py:

```
class ListFeedBack(ListView):
    template_name = 'feedback/list_feedback.html'
    model=Feedback
    paginate_by = 2
```

list_feedback.html:

```
{% extends 'feedback/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<h2>Все отзывы</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Номер</th>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Фамилия</th>
        <th>Отзывы</th>
        <th>Рейтинг</th>

    </tr>
    {% for i in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <th><a href="{{i.get_url}}">{{i.id}}</a></th>
        <th>{{i.name}}</th>
        <th>{{i.surname}}</th>
        <th>{{i.feedback}}</th>
        <th>{{i.rating}}</th>


    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
   <nav class="list-pages">
       <ul>
           {% for p in paginator.page_range %}
           <li class="page-num">
               <a href="?page={{p}}">{{p}}</a>
           </li>
           {% endfor %}
       </ul>
   </nav>
{% endblock %}`
```

Note: i also use base.html with empty navbar block

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>  {% block title %} {% endblock %}  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'feedback/field.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
   {% block content %}

   {% endblock %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'feedback/table.css' %}">
   {% block navbar %}

   {% endblock %}
    
</body>

</html>
```

Note: it tried to use  with favicon direction but i get the same error.

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('done', views.DoneView.as_view()),
    path('', views.FeedBackView.as_view()),
    path('list', views.ListFeedBack.as_view()),
    path('<int:id_feedback>', views.UpdateFeedbackView.as_view(), name='update_feed'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>', views.DetailFeedBack.as_view(),name='feedback_details'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.FeedBackViewUpdate.as_view(),name='feedback_details'),
]
```

styles.css

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #444;
}

a {
    color: #0059b2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #CC0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

img {max-width: 600px; height: auto;}

img.img-article-left {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

img.img-article-left.thumb {
    max-width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

p.link-read-post {
    text-align: right;
}
p.link-read-post a {
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background: #333671;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.article-panel {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #555;
}
div.article-panel p.first {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
div.article-panel p.last {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}

ul.list-articles {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.list-articles li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.table-page tr {height: 100%;}

.clear {clear: both;}

.header {
    background: #3F4137;
    height: 60px;
}

.logo {
    background: url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat 10px 5px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
}

ul.mainmenu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fdc073;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.mainmenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 18px 40px 0 30px;
}
ul.mainmenu li.logo {margin: 0;}
ul.mainmenu li.last {float: right;}

ul.mainmenu li a {
    color: #fdc073;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.mainmenu li a:hover {
    color: #FDA83D;
}

.panelitems {
    text-align: center;
}

ul.langitem {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 300px
}
ul.langitem li {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.langitem li.image {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.langitem li.descr {
    color: #777;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.langitem li a {
    color: #fdc073;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
ul.langitem li a:hover {
    color: #FDA83D;
}
div.button {
    background: #3F4137;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.table-content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.left-chapters {
    margin: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.left-chapters ul {
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.left-chapters ul li {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    color: #999;
}
.left-chapters ul li.selected {color: #0059b2; }
.left-chapters ul li a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.left-chapters ul li a:hover { color: #CC0000; }
.left-chapters ul li.share {margin: 60px 0 0 0;}
.left-chapters ul li.share p {margin: 30px 0 30px 0;}
.left-chapters ul li.share a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.left-chapters ul li.share a.share-yt {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../images/share_yt.png') no-repeat 0 0
}
.left-chapters ul li.share a.share-yt:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../images/share_yt.png') no-repeat 0 -30px
}

ul.tags-list {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tags-list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.tags-list li a {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.content {
    padding: 40px 20px 20px 40px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.breadcrumbs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li a {
    color: #0059b2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li a:hover { color: #CC0000; }
ul.breadcrumbs li:after{
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    content: "\2192";
}
ul.breadcrumbs li.last:after {content: "";}

ul.control {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.control li { float: left; padding: 0 0 0 10px;}
ul.control li.first:before {content: "\2190"; padding: 0 10px 0 0;}
ul.control li.last {float: right; padding: 0 40px 0 0;}
ul.control li.last:after {content: "\2192"; padding: 0 0 0 10px;}
ul.control li a { color: #0059b2; text-decoration: none; }
ul.control li a:hover { color: #CC0000; }

ul.content-table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 0 0 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size: 28px;
}
ul.content-table li {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
ul.content-table li a {
    color: #BB5715;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.content-table li a:hover {color: #F0711C;}

.content-text {
    margin: 60px 0 0 30px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Yandex Sans Display Light;
}
.content-text h1 {font-size: 32px;}

ul.lang-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px 0 0 0;
    background: #3F4137;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #959A82;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
}
ul.lang-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
ul.lang-list li.selected {color: #fdc073; border-bottom: 1px solid #fdc073;}
ul.lang-list li a {
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.lang-list li a:hover {color: #fdc073;}

.topic-subject .topic-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CC0000;
    margin-top: -16px;
}

.topic-subject .topic-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #777;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
}

.list-topic {
    margin: 40px 0 60px 0;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
}
.list-topic p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.list-topic ol {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    column-gap: 40px;
}
.list-topic ol li {
    display: list-item;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.list-topic ol li a {
    color: #0059b2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.list-topic ol li a:hover {color: #CC0000;}

.highlight {
    max-width: 350px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
.highlight p { margin: 0; }
.highlight .block {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.highlight .block p { margin: 0; }

.quote {
    background: url('../images/blockquote.png') no-repeat 0 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 70px;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-style: italic;
}

#footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background: #3F4137;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #aaa;
}

.form-input {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.form-label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.form-error ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #CC0000;
}

.form-button {
    min-width: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.list-pages {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.list-pages ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list-pages ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.list-pages a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.list-pages .page-num, .page-num-selected {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.list-pages .page-num:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #d0d0d0;
}
.list-pages .page-num-selected {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.list-pages .page-num-selected:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The solution you're seeking

I assume you want use the `styles.css` file you listed in the navbar. I don't see any `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` tag in your HTML template to load that file. Perhaps that is what you're missing.

If the css file you're trying to use is one of `feedback/table.css` and `feedback/field.css`, perhaps you haven't set up your [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/) to include these files?

#### The error you're seeing

The error for the favicon is unrelated; whenever you load a website in your browser, your browser makes a request to the `/favicon.ico` endpoint for the [favicon](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp) and expects your server to return an icon file. Since you don't have `favicon.ico` as a route in your urls.py, your server responds with 404.
You can fix this by either including a `<link rel="icon"...>` tag in your HTML header, or by serving the icon on the `/favicon.ico` path.

#### Some further notes

- You should try to keep `<link...>` tags in your HTML `<head>` rather than leaving them around the body as you do in your base.html
- You have two routes with `name='feedback_details'`, which is likely not what you want :)